# Retuning stream in AWS API Gateway -> Lambda function?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, content-type

I have created an API using AWS api gateway like `https://api.mydomain.com/v1/download?id=1234"`. The `download` resource has `GET` method. And the `GET` method is invoking `lambda` function using `Lambda Proxy Integration`.

The Lambda function needs to act as Proxy. It needs to resolve correct backend endpoint based on header `x-clientId` and then forward the request to that backend endpoint and return response as it is.  So it needs to be generic to handle GET request of different content-type.

My lambda function looks like ( .NET Core)

```
public async Task<APIGatewayProxyResponse> Route(APIGatewayProxyRequest input, ILambdaContext context)
{
    var clientId = headers["x-clientId"];            
    var mappings = new Mappings();
    var url = await mappings.GetBackendUrl(clientId, input.Resource);       

    var httpClient = new HttpClient();
    var response = await httpClient.GetAsync(url);
    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

    var proxyResponse = new APIGatewayProxyResponse()
    {
        Headers = new Dictionary<string, string>(),
        StatusCode = (int)System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK,
        IsBase64Encoded = false,
        Body = await response.Content.ReadAsString())
    };            
}
```

The handler above works as long as request and response's `content-type` is `application/json` or `application/xml`. However i am not sure how to handle response when backend returns stream.

For download API,  the backend returns `Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="somefilename` and ContentType may be one of the following:
`application/pdf`
`application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet`
`application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document`
`application/x-zip-compressed`
`application/octet-stream`

For these streams, How do i set `APIGatewayProxyResponse.Body`?

For Excel file I have tried setting body like below

```
    var proxyResponse = new APIGatewayProxyResponse()
    {
        Headers = new Dictionary<string, string>(),
        StatusCode = (int)System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK,
        IsBase64Encoded = true,
        Body = Convert.ToBase64String(await response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync())
    };  

proxyResponse.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");
proxyResponse.Headers.Add("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"Report.xlsx\"");
```

When i access the Url from the browser and try to open the file. I get error

`Excel cannot open the file`Report.xlsx`becuase the file format or file extension is not valid. Verify that the file has not been corrupted and that the extention matches the format of the file`

I think the issue is how i am setting the response body

**Update 1**
So based on [AWS doc](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2016/11/binary-data-now-supported-by-api-gateway/) Binary Data Now Supported by API Gateway. Now as per the documentation

> you can specify if you would like API Gateway to either pass the
>   Integration Request and Response bodies through, convert them to text
>   (Base64 encoding), or convert them to binary (Base64 decoding). These
>   options are available for HTTP, AWS Service, and HTTP Proxy
>   integrations. In the case of Lambda Function and Lambda Function Proxy
>   Integrations, which currently only support JSON, the request body is
>   always converted to JSON.

I am using Lambda Function Proxy, which currently support JSON. However the [example here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/binary-support-for-api-integrations-with-amazon-api-gateway/) shows how to do it with Lambda Proxy.
I think what i am missing here is **Binary Media Types** setting and **Method Response** settings. Below is my setting. Not sure if these settings are correct

**Binary Media**
[image]

**Method Response**
[image]

Comment: Answer if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51219067/download-files-using-aws-lambda?rq=1) might give some hints

Comment: as per the article i am setting `IsBase64Encoded=true` and body to Base64String but no luck

Answer (score 1):

here how solved it

1>add `Binary Media Types`. API->Settings->Binary Media Types -> add
`application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet`

2>In Method Response Add `Content-Disposition` and `Content-Type` headers for thestatus 200

[image]

3>In Integration Response map these headers to headers that are coming from the backend. And also set content handling `convert to binary`. (our backend api is returning file blob in body)

[image]

Comment: hi, i am having the same trouble with converting PDF. what I am getting with your configurations is = {"statusCode":200,"headers":{"Content-Type":"application/pdf","Content-Disposition":"attachment; filename=esspi.pdf"},"multiValueHeaders":null,"body":"JVBERi..........","isBase64Encoded":true} and it is not showing as PDF.